# How to access level property of nested node in mat-tree inside DOM?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular Material has vast amount of properties in its components (API).

For example: https://material.angular.io/components/tree/api#MatNestedTreeNode

How would I access `level` property from within HTML (what's the syntax)?

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource"
          [treeControl]="treeControl">
    <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let data; when: hasChild">
        <div>

                    How to access this node's properties?

        </div>
        <ul [class.example-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(data)">
            <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
        </ul>
    </mat-nested-tree-node>
    <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let data">
        <div>

                    How to access this node's properties?

        </div>
    </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

TS:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-tree',
    templateUrl: './tree.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./tree.component.scss']
})
export class MyTreeComponent {

    treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<Data>(d => d.children);
    dataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource<Data>();

    constructor() { }

    hasChild = (_: number, d: Data) => !!d.children && d.children.length > 0;
}
```

I know how to do it programmatically (with `@ViewChild`), but that won't do since component has many nodes, not one.

EDIT: Expanded source code.

EDIT 2: To align better with Z.Bolbol answer - modified title and adding comment - this question was created because I didn't know how to retrieve level property of node in mat-tree. It appears that You have to compute it yourself and since provided answer actually solves the original problem - it's accepted.
Said that - comments about `@ViewChildren` and `QueryList` are 100% correct and I did make them work following the link provided - it's just they were no use because level property is never used in nested trees (level is always equal to 0).

Comment: ViewChild, as you wrote, isn't working because the component has more than one node. Use QueryList instead and with .toArray() method you can get the single node where you can access all the properties you want.

Comment: You can use `@ViewChildren` with `QueryList` for more than one nodes.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I edited question with some more code. Could You please elaborate how QueryList would work? I mean it's a nested tree structure which has 2 types of nodes. How is List applicable here?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Level flag is only available for Flat tree and I think that it's computed at expansion time from parent level, root node gets Level 0 and then for each espanded node :

```
node.level = parentNode.level + 1 ;
```

So if you want to keep things simple just use a Falt tree instead of Nested tree.
If you like to keep using Nested tree for any reason you need to compute the level with custom method.

**ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-tree',
    templateUrl: './tree.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./tree.component.scss']
})
export class MyTreeComponent {

    treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<Data>(d => d.children);
    dataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource<Data>();

    constructor() { }

    hasChild = (_: number, d: Data) => !!d.children && d.children.length > 0;

  getLevel(data, node: Data) {
    let path = data.find(branch => {
      return this.treeControl
        .getDescendants(branch)
        .some(n => n.name === node.name);
    });

    return path ? this.getLevel(path.children, node) + 1 : 0 ; 
  }
}
```

**html**

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource"
          [treeControl]="treeControl">
    <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let data; when: hasChild">
        <div>

                    {{ getLevel(this.dataSource.data, node)}}
        </div>
        <ul [class.example-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(data)">
            <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
        </ul>
    </mat-nested-tree-node>
    <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let data">
        <div>

                    {{ getLevel(this.dataSource.data, node)}}

        </div>
    </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

Comment: This actually solved the original problem, but as edited in original question - comments under it are also correct.

Answer (score 2):

Mat-nested-tree-node / mat-tree-node has aria-level property by default, which can be used for this purpose.

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource"
      [treeControl]="treeControl">
<mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let data; when: hasChild" #nestedTreeNodeElement>
    <div>
        {{nestedTreeNodeElement.ariaLevel}}
    </div>
    <ul [class.example-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(data)">
        <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
    </ul>
</mat-nested-tree-node>
<mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let data" #treeNodeElement>
    <div>
       {{treeNodeElement.ariaLevel}}
    </div>
</mat-tree-node>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, thats not working with Firefox, but a very good solution for the other ones.

Comment: You can use treeNodeElement.getAttribute("aria-level"), which will work in Firefox as well as  Chrome.